# React .js/ Error al compilar. Babel-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, babeljs

espero que puedan ayudarme una vez mas, al intentar cargar un mapa de React-Leaflet se me rompe toda la aplicacion. Arrojando el siguiente error:
Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
|     if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current) {
>       const options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
|       element.instance.setStyle(options);
|       optionsRef.current = options;
```

Solo al hacer un import

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Title from '../Title/Title';
import ContactForm from './ContactForm';
import {warningMsg} from './../Alerts/Alert';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
```

el utlimo import, es el que no funciona.
Ya probe desistanlando node_modules, volviendo a instalar YARN, elminando yarn.lock, y varias soluciones mas, pero ningun fue efectiva. si alguno le paso agradezco y **MUCHAS GRACIAS!!**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te dejo la solución desde otra respuesta, esta en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat

Comment: Hola @EduardoValenzuelaGonzalez, gracias. ya habia leido la respuesta, pero la volvi y a leeer y entre uno de los tantos comentarios, encontra la respuesta. habia que borrar la carpeta de node_modules/cache, graciassss!!